# How to extract a Double from a string in Python?

Tags: python, printing

At the moment I have this but it only works for integers (whole numbers) not doubles:

```
S = "Weight is 3.5 KG"
weight = [int(i) for i in S.split() if i.isdigit()] 

print(weight)
```

result: `[]`

Comment: there is no double type in python, only a `float` type, which is what you are looking for

Comment: `i.isdigit()` will return `False` even `i='3.5'`. You can use `re` for this or `try-except`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so how would I amend my code to extract the float? Is there such a thing as .isfloat() ?

Comment: @KurtisDunphy No there isn't such method.

Comment: @Ch3steR OK, maybe I can check if i is a digit OR "." and concatenate the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to extract the floating point number:

```
import re

S = "Weight is 3.5 KG"
pattern = re.compile(r'\-?\d+\.\d+')

weights = list(map(float, re.findall(pattern, S)))
print(weights)
```

`re.findall()` will return you the list of numbers found in the text. 
The `map` function will convert the list results to floating point number. Since it returns a generator, you need to convert it to a `list`.

Comment: @taksapaka thank you very much. (there are no instances of 1.1. so this is no problem for me)

Comment: @KurtisDunphy There would be no instances in your list but I'm saying it matches those too. It matches more than just floats.

Comment: @tanksapka that pattern wouldn’t catch negative floats. Adding `\-?` prefix to it would fix it.

Comment: @A.Rom I amended the pattern. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re`

```
import re
print(re.findall('\d+\.\d+',S)
#['3.5']
```

---

Using `try-except`

```
for i in S.split():
    try:
        new.append(float(i))
    except Exception:
        pass

print(new)
#['3.5']
```

Comment: @KurtisDunphy Glad I helped. If it helped you please accept this as answer and upvote.

Comment: don't use `if float(i) : ...` just use `new.append(float(i))`. what if `i == '0'`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I wrote `if float(i):...` because i thought OP wanted to extract substring which is a float if he wants to store them as float he can use `new.append(float(i))`. I think it's worth mentioning though.

Comment: @Ch3steR no, my point is, if `float(x)` evaluates to `0.0` then it won't enter the if-block because `bool(0.0) is False`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good point. Didn't see that coming fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do the job for the example you placed:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    S = "Weight is 3.5 KG"

    # search for the dot (.)
    t = S.find('.')

    # check if the dot (.) exist in the string
    # make sure the dot (.) is not the last character
    # of the string
    if t > 0 and t+1 != len(S):
        # check the character before and after 
        # the dot (.)
        t_before = S[t-1]
        t_after = S[t+1]

        # check if the charactef before and after the 
        # dot (.) is a digit
        if t_before.isdigit() and t_after.isdigit():
            # split the string
            S_split = S.split()

            for x in S_split:
                if '.' in x:
                    print(float(x))
```

Output:

```
3.5
```

Comment: What if `x` is `'hello.'`? `float('hello.')` will throw Exception. Just because the substring contains a `.` doesn't make it a *float*.

Comment: @Ch3steR I modified it to take into account of your case